# How can I display a property key of a node in Neo4j's Browser

Tags: neo4j

For example if a node has a property 'name,' such that

```
MERGE (person:Person {name : UPPER(line.Name)})
```

How can I make sure that my match command always returns nodes with labels on top of them? Currently the returned nodes are blank, and I have to hover over them to see their names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Near the top of the box for your query results, you'll see a row of colored Node labels. Click the label you are interested in.
2. At the bottom of the query result box, you can now select the property to display on the nodes with that label. If your browser window is too narrow, the set of properties may not (completely) fit in the single line at the bottom; in this case, click the triangle on the right to display all the properties so that you can select the one you want.